# show the column names to go along with the sum

Tags: sql-server

am just doing some practice in SQL Server. My below query sums a quantity column but I also want to return the corresponding item number column and item description column with it. each time I try it tells me the item_no column is ambiguous. I have done some reading as to what this means but am still not clear on it. What am I missing?

```
declare @startdate int = '20161201'
declare @enddate int = '20170401'



SELECT  sum(qty) as total_units, item_no as item_number from fact_sales 
inner join dim_item 
on fact_sales.item_no=dim_item.item_no
where vendor_id = 'roche' and date_key between @startdate and @enddate 
order by fact_sales.item_no
```

Comment: Add GROUP BY item_no

Comment: It saying ambiguous because you have more than one `item_no` column, you should select this as `tblname.item_no`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing couple of things

```
DECLARE @startdate INT = '20161201'
DECLARE @enddate INT = '20170401'

SELECT sum(fact_sales.qty) AS total_units
    ,dim_item.item_no AS item_number
    ,dim_item.item_discription
FROM fact_sales
INNER JOIN dim_item ON fact_sales.item_no = dim_item.item_no
WHERE vendor_id = 'roche'
    AND date_key BETWEEN @startdate
        AND @enddate

GROUP BY dim_item.item_no,dim_item.item_discription
ORDER BY fact_sales.item_no
```

1. Group By
2. Prefixing column name with Table name/ Table alias

Comment: It's still saying item_no is ambiguous

Comment: I get this error: `Column 'dim_item.item_description' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

Comment: Include it in Group By. I am not having your table schema.. So I can't verify actual column names. I have updated my answer again.. @AdamNewman

Comment: Found the issue, your suggestions helped. Thank you